# Return error message if input is not string

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm trying to build an app that asks for input twice. First an integer after a string.

I want it to return an *error message* once the user inputs an integer for a string intended input and vice versa. I got through with returning an error message if the user inputs a string when it asks for an integer, but I'm having troubles returning an error message if the user inputs an integer when the code asks for a string.

Here's my code so far:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Input account number : ");
    input = s.nextLine();
}

while (!isDigit(input));
int acct = Integer.parseInt(input);

System.out.print("Input account name : ");
String name = s.nextLine();
```

Comment: Well, "5" *is* a string. If you'd like to return an error if the users enters a String that could be cast to an int - you'll have to handle that yourself.

Comment: Your code is currently returning nothing. Is this within a method that is supposed to return a result? Are you supposed to throw an exception if bad input is given?

Comment: You're going to need to define what 'a String' is in your context.  You could do regex matching, attempt to parse it as an integer and retry if it succeeds, etc.  But it is _always_ going to be a `String`.

Comment: It is within a method yes. I just didn't know if I should include the method here since it works, I just used it to elaborate my problem which is returning an error message if the user inputs an integer when it needs a string. Thank you

Comment: By strings I mean letters, I apologize for vagueness but it is what that's being taught to us in school. I want to know how to return error if the user inputs a number when the code asks for letters. Thank you

Comment: Use regex expression with Pattern object.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This would allow for inputs like "34f" to be accepted. If you want to forbid [0-9], you should use regex or see if the String.contains() [0-9].

You could just check if some String can be cast to an int - and if it can't, mark that as your success condition.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    /**
     * Main.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Don't enter a number: ");
        s = in.nextLine();

        if(isInt(s)) {
            System.out.println("Seriously? That was a number.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a number - thanks!");
        }

        in.close();
    }

    /**
     * Accept a String and return true if it can be parsed as an int.
     * @param s
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isInt(String s) {
        boolean res;

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            res = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            res = false;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. After all, what if the numeric value is to large for an int? your method would return false for isInt.

Comment: Well to be fair - if it's too large for an int, it's not an int in the Java sense of the word. I realize it could still be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

For the numeric value you could just try to convert it to an int. For the alphabetic characters only, I would use a simple regex matcher `^[A-Za-z]+$`.

Example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class InputDemo {

    private static final Pattern CHARS = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]+$");

    private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InputDemo demo = new InputDemo();
        final int accountNumber = demo.readInteger("Input account number: ");
        final String accountName = demo.readAlpha("Input account name: ");

    }

    private int readInteger(String prompt) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(prompt);
                return Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            }
        }
    }

    private String readAlpha(String prompt) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            final String input = in.nextLine();
            if (CHARS.matcher(input).matches()) {
                return input;
            }
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
        }
    }
}
```